# Android Layout - How To Slide Down Show Update Message in Android in GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

In my gridview I need that when you're at the top and drag it down to appear as a message is seen on the facebook app

example in the picture of what I need

[Screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nLIx1p5lAQV3MxZ0JRNVJoVzQ/edit?usp=sharing)

[Screen Update](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nLIx1p5lAQa1V3a0ZsN1I3bDA/edit?usp=sharing)

My Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:columnWidth="74dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: resolved!!!

[action bar refresh similar g+ app](https://github.com/marcostomazini/ActionBar-PullToRefresh)
[listview refresh similar facebook app](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh this library to implement pull to refresh grid view

Comment: I did not know the term to be searched after it found several .. thanks +1

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh